# BTable Filter with a Function

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

i've been struggling for almost 6 hours with this, but i didn't find a way to accomplish what i need.

the thing is that i need to filter the table of bootstrap vue with a function, but i can't make it work, there is a step that i need, but i can't find it.

here it is a jsfiddle that i grab from the web, that has the simple b-table with property filter.

https://jsfiddle.net/rothariger/oxbrhcqk/1/

now if you check on this example I've replaced the property for a function, but, it just get called in the load, when you change the filter textbox, it doesn't do anything, and here is where i think i'm missing a step.

https://jsfiddle.net/rothariger/oxbrhcqk/3/

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
      isActive: true,
      age: 40,
      name: {
        first: 'Dickerson',
        last: 'Macdonald'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 21,
      name: {
        first: 'Larsen',
        last: 'Shaw'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 9,
      state: 'success',
      name: {
        first: 'Mitzi',
        last: 'Navarro'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 89,
      name: {
        first: 'Geneva',
        last: 'Wilson'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: true,
      age: 38,
      name: {
        first: 'Jami',
        last: 'Carney'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 27,
      name: {
        first: 'Essie',
        last: 'Dunlap'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: true,
      age: 40,
      name: {
        first: 'Dickerson',
        last: 'Macdonald'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 21,
      name: {
        first: 'Larsen',
        last: 'Shaw'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 26,
      name: {
        first: 'Mitzi',
        last: 'Navarro'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 22,
      name: {
        first: 'Geneva',
        last: 'Wilson'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: true,
      age: 38,
      name: {
        first: 'Jami',
        last: 'Carney'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 27,
      name: {
        first: 'Essie',
        last: 'Dunlap'
      }

    }],
    fields: {
      name: {
        label: 'Person Full name',
        sortable: true
      },
      age: {
        label: 'Person age',
        sortable: true
      },
      isActive: {
        label: 'is Active'
      },
      actions: {
        label: 'Actions'
      }
    },
    currentPage: 1,
    perPage: 5,
    filter: null
  },
  methods: {
    details(item) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(item));
    },
    filterGrid(val) {
      console.log(val);
      return true;
    }
  }
})
```

any info on what i have to do?

regards.

Comment: yes, it does work, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Vue Bootstrap introdues:](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/),

> The filter prop value can be a string, a RegExp or a function
>   reference. If a function is provided, the first argument is the
>   original item record data object. The function should return true if
>   the record matches your criteria or false if the record is to be
>   filtered out.

Then look into [the source code at Vue Bootstrap Github](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/table/table.js#L790), you will find **Vue Bootstrap** **only** invoke **your filter function** inside one computed property=**computedItems**.

So for your case:

```
filterGrid(val) {
  console.log(val);
  return true;
}
```

It **does not trigger any reactivity** (print then always return true), so it will do nothing (computed property=computedItems will not be re-calculated, so filter function will not be executed either).

so one simple filter function with reactivity will be like:

```
filterGrid(val){
    return !this.filter || JSON.stringify(val).includes(this.filter)
}
```

Also you can involves other data/prop/computed property, the filter function will be executed also when reactivity is triggered.

**The full demo**:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
      isActive: true,
      age: 40,
      name: {
        first: 'Dickerson',
        last: 'Macdonald'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 21,
      name: {
        first: 'Larsen',
        last: 'Shaw'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 9,
      state: 'success',
      name: {
        first: 'Mitzi',
        last: 'Navarro'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 89,
      name: {
        first: 'Geneva',
        last: 'Wilson'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: true,
      age: 38,
      name: {
        first: 'Jami',
        last: 'Carney'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 27,
      name: {
        first: 'Essie',
        last: 'Dunlap'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: true,
      age: 40,
      name: {
        first: 'Dickerson',
        last: 'Macdonald'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 21,
      name: {
        first: 'Larsen',
        last: 'Shaw'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 26,
      name: {
        first: 'Mitzi',
        last: 'Navarro'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 22,
      name: {
        first: 'Geneva',
        last: 'Wilson'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: true,
      age: 38,
      name: {
        first: 'Jami',
        last: 'Carney'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 27,
      name: {
        first: 'Essie',
        last: 'Dunlap'
      }

    }],
    fields: {
      name: {
        label: 'Person Full name',
        sortable: true
      },
      age: {
        label: 'Person age',
        sortable: true
      },
      isActive: {
        label: 'is Active'
      },
      actions: {
        label: 'Actions'
      }
    },
    currentPage: 1,
    perPage: 5,
    filter: null
  },
  methods: {
    details(item) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(item));
    },
    filterGrid(val){
     return !this.filter || JSON.stringify(val).includes(this.filter)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>

<!-- Add this after vue.js -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="justify-content-centermy-1 row">

    <b-form-fieldset horizontal label="Rows per page" class="col-6" :label-size="6">
      <b-form-select :options="[{text:5,value:5},{text:10,value:10},{text:15,value:15}]" v-model="perPage">
      </b-form-select>
    </b-form-fieldset>

    <b-form-fieldset horizontal label="Filter" class="col-6" :label-size="2">
      <b-form-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Type to Search"></b-form-input>
    </b-form-fieldset>
  </div>

  <!-- Main table element -->
  <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields" :current-page="currentPage" :per-page="perPage" :filter="filterGrid">
    <template slot="name" scope="item">
      {{item.value.first}} {{item.value.last}}
    </template>
    <template slot="isActive" scope="item">
      {{item.value?'Yes :)':'No :('}}
    </template>
    <template slot="actions" scope="item">
      <b-btn size="sm" @click="details(item.item)">Details</b-btn>
    </template>
  </b-table>

  <div class="justify-content-center row my-1">
    <b-pagination size="md" :total-rows="this.items.length" :per-page="perPage" v-model="currentPage" />
  </div>
</div>
```