# How to filter b-table rows using a custom filter-function?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to filter out some rows in a bootstrap-vue table using a custom filter function.

I wrote a function that takes two arguments - a row object and an empty filter argument, and returns true or false, as in the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#custom-filter-function).

I have tried to use the code provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415889/btable-filter-with-a-function#comment96462273_52416037) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55489965/3969204) answers, but they doesn't work either.

I've also tried to put `console.log(row, filter)` into the filterTable method but it doesn't write anything to the console.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table 
      striped hover 
      :items="items" 
      :filter=null 
      :filter-function="filterTable"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items: [
          { age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
      }
    },

    methods: {
      filterTable(row) {
        if (row.age >= 40) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to display people who are younger than 40 years old, but it displays all the records instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The criteria you pass to the filter function must be placed on the filter property in order to be reactive. For example you can add a new property e.g. `criteria` to your data object and assign it to `:filter`. The `filter` property expects a value of type String, RegExp, Object or Array. If you assign a number to it, you will get a warning. The criteria for your filter function will be passed as a second argument.

See example below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      criteria: "40",
      items: [{
          age: 40,
          first_name: 'Dickerson',
          last_name: 'Macdonald'
        },
        {
          age: 21,
          first_name: 'Larsen',
          last_name: 'Shaw'
        },
        {
          age: 89,
          first_name: 'Geneva',
          last_name: 'Wilson'
        },
        {
          age: 38,
          first_name: 'Jami',
          last_name: 'Carney'
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    filterTable(row, filter) {
      if (row.age >= filter) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.21/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.21/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :filter="criteria" :filter-function="filterTable">
    </b-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey that was helpful for me as well. I would like to know how can we edit criteria dynamically using select field. Suppose my table displays some rows with one of its column being department. So using a select field if I select HR dept then my table should only show rows with their dept column being HR. Can you please help me out....

Comment: I figured it out. But I still don't know whether a vue table accept more than one filter i.e select field and search field

Comment: Maybe this issue helps you: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1667